# parsing via json not getting data

Tags: android, json

[image]

I am parsing json data in my code. The json data is as shown in the image. why i am not getting while hitting url.
I think accessing problem . restaurants in array after that in object then items so in the code accessing problem.

So could anyone help me ? where i am lacking in this ?

```
public class ListViewActivity extends Activity {
    // Log tag
    private static final String TAG = ListViewActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    // change here url of server api
    private static final String url = "https://comida-95724.herokuapp.com/api/v1/restaurants/get_featured_restaurants";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    private ListView listView;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_listview);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, movieList);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Movie movie = movieList.get(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(ListViewActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("name", movie.getName());
                intent.putExtra("average_ratings", movie.getAverage_ratings());
                intent.putExtra("full_address", movie.getAddress());
                intent.putExtra("image_url", movie.getThumbnailUrl());
                intent.putExtra("cuisine",movie.getCuisine());
                intent.putExtra("cost",movie.getCost());
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
         pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Please Keep patience.Its loading...");

        pDialog.show();

         JsonObjectRequest movieReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
        url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        hidePDialog();
                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {
                                JSONArray restaurantsJSONArray=response.getJSONArray("restaurants");
                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                Movie movie = new Movie();
                                //movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                                movie.setName(obj.getString("name"));
                                //movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                                movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("org_image_url"));
                                movie.setAverage_ratings(obj.getString("average_ratings"));
                                movie.setCuisine(obj.getString("cuisine"));
                                movie.setAddress(obj.getJSONObject("address").getString("area"));
                               // movie.setAddress(obj.getJSONObject("address").getString("full_address"));
                                movie.setCost(obj.getString("cost"));

                                movieList.add(movie);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }


                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                hidePDialog();

            }
        });


        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        hidePDialog();
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
JsonObjectRequest movieReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
        urlJsonObj, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
```

for access your jsonArray:

```
JSONArray restaurantsJSONArray=response.getJSONArray("restaurants");
```

try this:

```
JsonObjectRequest movieReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
        url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        JSONArray   

           restaurantsJSONArray=response.getJSONArray("restaurants");

                        hidePDialog();
                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < restaurantsJSONArray.length(); i++) {
                            try {

                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                Movie movie = new Movie();
                                //movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                                movie.setName(obj.getString("name"));
                                //movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                                movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("org_image_url"));
                                movie.setAverage_ratings(obj.getString("average_ratings"));
                                movie.setCuisine(obj.getString("cuisine"));
                                movie.setAddress(obj.getJSONObject("address").getString("area"));
                               // movie.setAddress(obj.getJSONObject("address").getString("full_address"));
                                movie.setCost(obj.getString("cost"));

                                movieList.add(movie);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }


                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                hidePDialog();

            }
        });


        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
    }
```

Comment: i have made changes and edited code Please see i am not getting

Comment: JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i); Error in this line

Comment: @user6313669 JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i); change it to JSONObject obj =restaurantsJSONArray.getJSONObject(i);

Answer (score 1):

Use `JsonObjectRequest` instead of `JsonArrayRequest` because as post image contains `JSONObject` as root item instead-of `JSONArray`.

and `restaurants` is `JSONArray` of `JSONObject`. first get `restaurants` for `onResponse` JSONObject parameter before getting all JSONObject's from it:

```
JSONArray restaurantsJSONArray=response.getJSONArray("restaurants");
```

Now use for-loop to get JSONObject from `restaurantsJSONArray` .

Comment: i have made changes and edited code Please see i am not getting

Comment: @user6313669: move `JSONArray restaurantsJSONArray=response.getJSONArray("restaurants");` line outside for loop and use `for (int i = 0; i < restaurantsJSONArray.length(); i++) { JSONObject obj = restaurantsJSONArray.getJSONObject(i);` instead of `for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);`